# strtotime and date not outputting correctly

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am having trouble echoing out the correct unix timestamp for the date saved in the database.

```
$activeWorkRow['WorkDate'] = "9/24/2015 1:45:53 PM";
$locateDate = $activeWorkRow['WorkDate'];
$locateDate = str_replace('/', '-', $locateDate);
//$locateDate = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($locateDate));
//$locateDate = strtotime(date($locateDate));

echo $locateDate."<br>";
```

Output:

```
9-24-2015 1:45:53 PM
```

Next:

```
$locateDate = $activeWorkRow['WorkDate'];
$locateDate = str_replace('/', '-', $locateDate);
$locateDate = date('m-d-Y', strtotime(locateDate));
//$locateDate = strtotime(date($locateDate));
```

Output:

```
12-31-1969
```

I am trying to get to the unix timestamp so I can compare it with others.

Comment: What timezone is your server in?

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is the `str_replace('/', '-', $locateDate);`. Your date is given as `m/d/y` and with that replacement you're converting it to `m-d-y`.

But `strtotime` treats `-` as indicator for the European `d-m-y` format. And in that format, `9/24/2015` is not a valid date, leading to your observed output (which is equal to `date('m-d-Y', 0)`).

Simply skip the `str_replace`:

```
$activeWorkRow['WorkDate'] = "9/24/2015 1:45:53 PM";
$locateDate = $activeWorkRow['WorkDate'];
echo strtotime($locateDate);
```

Output:

```
1443116753
```

Cf. [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) for more details and caveats:

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and
>   the separator is a dash (-, the date string is parsed as y-m-d.

Note that when displaying those timestamps you might also want to think about timezones (`strtotime` uses the default unless specified otherwise), but as long as you're only comparing timestamps generated by the same function you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL you can say:

mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP();

```
<?php  
$hostname="your_hostname";  
$username="your_username";  
$password="your_password";  
$db = "your_dbname";   
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);  
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP()') as $row) {  
    echo "<tr>";  
    echo "<td>" . $row['UNIX_TIMESTAMP()'] . "</td>";   
    echo "</tr>";  
}  
?>
```

or if you need the Unix Stamp time for a specified date try:

mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-01-01 12:00:00');

```
<?php  
$hostname="your_hostname";  
$username="your_username";  
$password="your_password";  
$db = "your_dbname";  
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);  
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2016-01-01 12:00:00")') as $row) {  
    echo "<tr>";  
    echo "<td>" . $row['UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2016-01-01 12:00:00")'] . "</td>";  
    echo "</tr>";  
}  
?>
```

Comment: It's stored using varchar and not datetime. I think thats why I get a 0 instead of what it should output

Comment: You can input a varchar to this function: SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP($activeWorkRow['WorkDate'])

Comment: $timestamp = strtotime($mysqltime);
    echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);